# Optimize query with self-joins and group bys in where clause

Tags: sql-server

This is my old query:

```
Select AccountID,AccountDesc,
    CASE 
    WHEN NOT EXISTS (select AccountID from #B where #B.AccountID = P1.AccountID) THEN cast(cast(GETDATE() as date) as varchar)     
    ELSE cast(cast(CreateDate as date) as varchar)
    END 
    FROM #A P1
    WHERE P1.EndDate = (Select max(EndDate) from #A P2 where P1.AccountID = P2.AccountID and P2.Categ1 = 'F'
    group by P2.AccountID) 
    and P1.StartDate = (Select max(StartDate) from #A P2 where P1.AccountID = P2.AccountID and P2.Categ1 = 'F'
    group by P2.AccountID) 
    and P1.CreateDate = (Select max(CreateDate ) from #A P2 where P1.AccountID = P2.AccountID and P2.Categ1 = 'F'
    group by P2.AccountID) 
    and P1.NewStartDate= (Select max(NewStartDate) from #A P2 where P1.AccountID = P2.AccountID and P2.Categ1 = 'F'
    group by P2.AccountID)
```

I wanted to get rid of the repetitive self-joins and group bys in the where clause, so I got rid of the "Categ1 = F" part and put it up in the work table #A's where clause instead when I am inserting into it. And, I figured the self-join was only for getting the MAX values, so since I made the work table I didn't think I would need this self-joins anymore. So, I end up with this new query:

```
Select AccountID,AccountDesc,
    CASE 
    WHEN NOT EXISTS (select AccountID from #B where #B.AccountID = P1.AccountID) THEN cast(cast(GETDATE() as date) as varchar)     
    ELSE cast(cast(CreateDate as date) as varchar)
    END 
    FROM #A P1
    WHERE P1.EndDate = (Select max(EndDate) from #A)
    and P1.StartDate = (Select max(StartDate) from #A) 
    and P1.CreateDate = (Select max(CreateDate) from #A) 
    and P1.NewStartDate= (Select max(NewStartDate) from #A)
```

But this is not returning the same number of records, I believe because I also deleted the "Group By" clauses in the where conditions?

Can someone help me make this original query faster, but still return the same results?

Comment: All those subqueries are not helping at all. Sample data and expected results would help here as well.

Comment: Larnu, thanks for the comment...it will take me awhile to figure out how to provide sample data (some reasons are cleaning personal info, very large dataset, and also I've never added data on stack overflow)...I will try to see how to work this in somehow.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? This query can be re-written to use window functions (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a subquery and join that in so the calcs on happen once.

```
;with cte as
(
select Account,max(EndDate) ED ,max(StartDate) SD,max(CreateDate ) CD ,max(NewStartDate) NSD 
from #a
where Categ1 = 'F'
group by Account
)
Select AccountID,AccountDesc,
    CASE 
    WHEN NOT EXISTS (select AccountID from #B where #B.AccountID = P1.AccountID) THEN cast(cast(GETDATE() as date) as varchar)     
    ELSE cast(cast(CreateDate as date) as varchar)
    END 
 FROM #A p1
     join cte on p1.Account=cte.Account
           and p1.StartDate=cte.SD
           and p1.EndDate = cte.ED
           and p1.CreateDate = cte.CD 
           and p1.NewStartDate=cte.NSD
```

here is another enhancement:

```
CASE 
    WHEN NOT EXISTS (select AccountID from #B where #B.AccountID = P1.AccountID) THEN cast(cast(GETDATE() as date) as varchar)     
    ELSE cast(cast(CreateDate as date) as varchar)
```

can get changed by left joining #B

```
;with cte as
(
select Account,max(EndDate) ED ,max(StartDate) SD,max(CreateDate ) CD ,max(NewStartDate) NSD 
from #a
where Categ1 = 'F'
group by Account
)
Select AccountID,AccountDesc,
    case when p2.Account is not null 
         then cast(CreateDate as varchar(10)) 
         else cast(cast(getdate() as date) as varchar(10)) end
 FROM #A p1
     join cte on p1.Account=cte.Account
           and p1.StartDate=cte.SD
           and p1.EndDate = cte.ED
           and p1.CreateDate = cte.CD 
           and p1.NewStartDate=cte.NSD
     left join #B p2 on p1.Account=p2.Account
```

Comment: This works well! It's indeed faster and returns the same number of records. I tried using a CTE but then somehow I thought it wouldn't be helpful....but now I see the reason it's helpful is in applying the group-by function to each where condition, but while the query engine only had to calculate it once. Thank you!

Comment: Remember that it is always best (at least with DBs) to try to do set analysis vs a single row.

Comment: As a follow-up question, let's say I now want to select another column like 'EmployeeID' in the final query, from #A....or I want to select more additional columns. Would this method be inefficient because if #A is the very-large data set, it's like I am querying it twice, which would become slow if querying many columns?

Comment: There is really no extra burden to add columns from #A into the final select. The work is already done.

Comment: When I select only these 3 columns AccountID and AccountDesc and CreateDate as shown here, my query takes like 30 seconds. When I select a bunch more columns like "Select AccountID,AccountDesc, ColA, ColB,ColC,ColD,ColE,ColF,ColG..." then the query goes to 3 minutes, and the new change with joining #B didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

To start with: All those `GROUP BY AccountID` clauses in your query are superfluous, as the subqueries always only select data for one AccountID anyway.

What's been tried in the `WHERE` clause is this:

```
WHERE (AccountID, EndDate, StartDate, CreateDate, NewStartDate) IN
(
  SELECT AccountID, MAX(EndDate), MAX(StartDate), MAX(CreateDate), MAX(NewStartDate)
  FROM #A
  WHERE Categ1 = 'F'
  GROUP BY AccountID
)
```

SQL Server, however, doesn't support this syntax. So convert this to `EXISTS`:

```
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1
  FROM #A P2
  WHERE P2.AccountID = P1.AccountID AND P2.Categ1 = 'F'
  HAVING P1.EndDate = MAX(P2.EndDate)
     AND P1.StartDate = MAX(P2.StartDate)
     AND P1.CreateDate = MAX(P2.CreateDate)
     AND P1.NewStartDate = MAX(P2.NewStartDate) 
)
```

Comment: Ok, this is insightful - I already accepted another answer, but your explanation makes sense and I will also give it a shot too. It's nice to see multiple ways of handling the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I Believe this will help you out

```
Select AccountID,AccountDesc,
     CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (select AccountID from #B where #B.AccountID = P1.AccountID) THEN cast(cast(GETDATE() as date) as varchar)     
     ELSE cast(cast(CreateDate as date) as varchar) END 
  FROM #A P1
    CROSS APPLY (
                  SELECT max(EndDate) EndDate, max(StartDate) StartDate, max(CreateDate ) CreateDate ,max(NewStartDate)NewStartDate 
                  FROM #A P2
                  WHERE P1.AccountID = P2.AccountID and P2.Categ1 = 'F'
                 ) AS P3
    WHERE P1.EndDate = P3.EndDate AND P1.StartDate = P3.StartDate
    AND P1.CreateDate = P3.CreateDate AND P1.NewStartDate = p3.NewStartDate
```